# Got error when use the GAE storage API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the GAE cloud API to upload image to the storage based on this document https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java
and get error as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/MoreObjects
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/160

update your Guava to 18.0 at least.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

By the way, the Guice has Guava dependency, so check it firstly.